# How to access EC2 server (localhost:PORT) from Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I am running a minimalist express webserver on an EC2 (ubuntu).

```
const app = require('express')()
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server listening...')
})
```

How can I access this server from a public IP?

For my EC2 instance:

- Have enabled HTTP, HTTPS, RDP, UDP, SSH with the "Anywhere" option in my security groups.
- Have Enabled Elastic IP as well (xx.xxx.xx.xx). But http://xx.xxx.xx.xx Or https://xx.xxx.xx.xx/ returns page not found.
- Also tried the above server with port 443, but with port 443, the "node app.js" throws an error.

Thanks

Comment: Your code suggests that the web server is running on port 3001. Therefore, you would need to connect to `http://x.x.x.x:3001`. The security group would also need to allow access on port 3001 (or _Anywhere_).

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that the web server is running on port 3001.

Therefore, you would need to connect to `http://x.x.x.x:3001`. The Security Group would also need to allow access on port 3001 (or *Anywhere*).